# BitmapFont.draw performance issue after exceeding certain number of characters

Tags: libgdx

Libgdx: 1.8
Windows 8.1 PRO

When exceeding certain number of character, in this case 51, the cpu usage jumps from steady 2-3% to over 30%.
Changing a font does not have any effect.

```
public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {
    public GameAssetManager assetManager;
    public SpriteBatch batch;
    BitmapFont font;

    static final String text =
            ".........." + // 10 characters
            ".........." +
            ".........." +
            ".........." +
            ".........." +
            "."; // add "." and check task manager

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"));
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
        parameter.characters = FreeTypeFontGenerator.DEFAULT_CHARS;
        parameter.size = 48;
        parameter.color = Color.WHITE;
        font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
        System.out.println("text length is " + text.length());
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        font.draw(batch, text, 0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - font.getAscent());
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I don't have a profiler to point exactly to the problem.

EDIT:

After spending some quality time with the issue I came up with nothing that works.
Minimal example:

```
public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {
    public SpriteBatch batch;
    BitmapFont font;
    BitmapFontCache fontCache;

    static final String text =
            ".........." + // 10 characters
            ".........." +
            ".........." +
            ".........." +
            ".........." +
            "..";

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"));
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
        parameter.characters = FreeTypeFontGenerator.DEFAULT_CHARS;
        parameter.size = 48;
        parameter.color = Color.WHITE;
        font = generator.generateFont(parameter);

        fontCache = font.newFontCache();
        fontCache.addText(text, 100, 100);
        System.out.println("text length is " + text.length());
    }

    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        fontCache.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

As I said before the performance after exceeding some number of characters is awful. The situation is similar for static (not generated at runtime) bitmap font. 
Since `BitmapFontCache` is internally used by `Label` etc. this behavior applies also to those classes.

Any insight welcome.

Comment: What type of object is `text`? If its not a BitmapFontCache, try using one. BTW, JDK comes with a profiler so you probably do have one.

Comment: @Tenfour04 `text` is of `String` type. Check the code. Thanks, I'll check how to run it with IntelliJ.

Comment: @Tenfour04, `BitmapFont` class is already using `BitmapFontCache` internally. But if noone is going to suggest something I'll try to dive a bit into the implementation.

Comment: It does, but it recomputes the cache each time you call `draw`. If you prepare the cache in `create` then it won't have to recompute it each time you draw it.